# Mass to area to mass/min

Tags: time-series, sampling

Given an collection of mass values (in $g$) which are samples collected over a minute in a moving-window fashion (thus their sum represents the mass per minute observed in the system), and a formula which derives an area (in $cm^2$) for each value (based on certain assumptions about the mass distribution -- e.g., by using the cross-sectional area of a sphere of that mass):

Is it possible, knowing only the sum of those areas (thus an area per minute value) and the single-value mass-area conversion formula used, to determine an exact or approximate value for the mass-per-minute (the sum of the original sample)?

If not, what other information would be required and how would it be used to calculate the mass-per-minute value?

Comment: My head hurts.  Can you write this with shorter but more sentences? (sorry).

Comment: An explicit example of the data would help. The answer will depend on the nature of the mass-area conversion formula, so you should try to tell us more about that, too.

Comment: To rephrase (correctly, I hope):  You have a function $f:G\to A$ (mass to area) and you want to know if you can estimate $\sum g_i$ given you've observed $\sum f(g_i)$?

Comment: Yes, that sounds about right.  And the example $f$ I gave above would be $A = \pi ((3 G/(4 \pi)) ^ {2/3})$.  But I'm interested in finding something that could work with a couple of other functions too.

Comment: Sorry, the formula got mangled a bit.  But I hope it's obvious what I meant.  Volume of a sphere with density=1 and the specified mass, solving for the radius and then obtaining the cross-sectional area via a circle of that radius.